# Is there any way I can install nginx with tcp_proxy module as a ubuntu package?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've installed my nginx via the ppa package

```
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx
apt-get install nginx
```

which works just fine. But now I need to add support for websockets for my socket.io app. I found [some tutorials](http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets), but generally the process is to download the source and recompile nginx with the tcp_proxy module.

Is there any way I can do this with the package manager, so that I don't have to compile it manualy? I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 if that's of any relevance.

Comment: There is no ready package for that. You should start with `apt-get source nginx`, and recompile it with this module. And don't forget to use something like `sudo checkinstall --pkgname nginx --pkgversion 1.2-tcl --install` instead of `make install`.

Comment: And finally I [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395807/nginx-close-upstream-connection-after-request). Please check this question - it's about HTTP 1.1 in nginx since 1.1.4.